# Does "consult" mean "ask for permission"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Given the following sentence:

> The manager may not incur debt without consulting the board.

Does that mean that the manager must have board permission to incur debt, or only that the manager must hear what the board has to say about the matter before making his or her own decision (possibly contrary to the board's opinion)?

Comment: It could be either one.  Most likely, the manager needs approval from the board to incur debt, but it is ambiguous.  Consult is defined as "have discussions or confer with (someone), typically before undertaking a course of action." [[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/consult)]  Technically, the definition would lead to the conclusion that the manager is simply listening to the board's opinion before making their own decision.  Both answers could be correct (based on the information given).

Comment: Why are people providing answers as comments?

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket You are right; I shouldn't have put it in the comments.  I figured that my answer was too brief to warrant a full answer, but I will not do it again.  Thanks for pointing it out to me.

Comment: @JohnB.You're welcome. No problem. If you want, you can just cut and paste your comment into an answer and delete your comment (don't forget to make sure the link still works).  I can do it for you, but then it looks like I wrote your excellent answer, and I'm not one to take credit for someone else's efforts. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One assumes that "the board" has the power to govern the manager's actions. Hence the fact that the manager needs to "consult" would effectively mean asking permission. The board could always say "don't".

**Indeed the OED confirms this is the case - see their sense 6a**. (*Consult*) when used of a person means seeking permission or approval.

> 6. To ask advice of, seek counsel from; to have recourse to for instruction, guidance, or professional advice.
>
> **a. (a person) Also in modern use, to seek permission or approval from
> (a person) for a
> proposed action.**
>
> 1930   D. L. Sayers Strong Poison xiv. 183   I have determined to put
> my property in Trust with you, so that you may have full power to
> handle everything according to your own discretion, without having to
> consult me every time.
>
> 1985   N.Y. Times 7 July ii. 25/2   Before selecting the designs, the
> Secretary of the Treasury must consult the chairmen of the Statue of
> Liberty–Ellis Island Foundation Inc. and the Federal Commission of
> Fine Arts.